# How to compare Years in Linq for Date Fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the below code to compare the Year of two Dates:

```
public string GetResultWbyYears()
    {
        using (var context = new DbEntity())
        {
            int yeat = DateTime.Now.Year;
            var holidays = (from rl in context.HolidayMasters
                            where rl.Isactive == true && rl.Isdelete == false //&& rl.HolidayDate.Year == yeat
                            orderby rl.HolidayDate ascending
                            select new HolidayEntity
                            {
                                HolidayDesc = rl.HolidayDesc,
                                HolidayDate = rl.HolidayDate,
                                HolidayId = rl.HolidayId

                            }).ToList().AsEnumerable().Select(x => new HolidayEntity()
            {
                HolidayDesc = x.HolidayDesc,
                HolidayDate = x.HolidayDate,
                Isactive = x.Isactive,
                Isdelete = x.Isdelete,
                HolidayId = x.HolidayId,
                Zones = GetZonesWithSelectedForHolidays(x.HolidayId)
            }).ToList();

            holidays = holidays.Where(n => n.HolidayDate.Year == yeat).ToList();
        }
```

Not Getting why the above is not working.. Please help me how can i get the result by year.

I have searched on google and found some articles doing the same thing i have done above,but this is not working for me. that's why i have posted the question.

Comment: Why do you select `IEnumerable<HolidayEntity>`, then convert it to `List`, then select `IEnumerable<HolidayEntity>` again? Your `Isactive` and `Isdelete` will always be default values (`false`, I guess).

Comment: do you have any error? your code looks ok to me

Comment: @kienct89 no error. but always return 0 records. even in DB we have records for current ear

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, these two are nullable so there is no default value for these.  Secondly the second IEnumerable<HolidayEntity> is to get zones for each holiday

Comment: @RamSingh Moreover, your method returns `List<HolidayEntity>` while return type of the method is `string`.

Comment: @RamSingh What is the type of `context.HolidayMasters`? Show the declaration.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev i am using EDMX, and it is table definition, you ant to post me that?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes, i am returning string after some calculation

Comment: This should work for you:holidays = holidays.Where(t => Convert.ToDateTime(t.HolidayDate).Year == yeat).ToList();

Comment: @Learning it throws error.. i have already checked this

Comment: What is the datatype for this:x.HolidayDate and how it it store in your table.just give me any sample output

Comment: have you tried this:holidays = holidays.Where(n => n.HolidayDate.Value.Year== yeat).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select `IEnumerable<HolidayEntity>`, then convert it to `List`, losing `Isactive` and `Isdelete` values as they will be default, then select `IEnumerable<HolidayEntity>` again.
There is actually no need in this.

Your LINQ can look much prettier:

```
public string GetResultWbyYears()
{
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    using (var context = new DbEntity())
    {
        var result = context.HolidayMasters
            .Where(hm => hm.Isactive && !hm.Isdelete && hm.HolidayDate.Year == year)
            .OrderBy(hm => hm.HolidayDate)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in result)
            item.Zones = GetZonesWithSelectedForHolidays(item.HolidayId); 
    }
}
```

or in another way:

```
public string GetResultWbyYears()
{
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    using (var context = new DbEntity())
    {
        var result = (from hm in dbSet
            where hm.Isactive && !hm.Isdelete && hm.HolidayDate.Year == 2015
            orderby hm.HolidayDate ascending
            select hm).ToList();

        foreach (var item in result)
            item.Zones = GetZonesWithSelectedForHolidays(item.HolidayId); 
    }
}
```

I suppose that your `context.HolidayMasters` is of type `DbSet<HolidayEntity`, since it has all properties with the same names. Otherwise, use one `Select`:

```
public string GetResultWbyYears()
{
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    using (var context = new DbEntity())
    {
        var result = (from hm in dbSet
            where hm.Isactive && !hm.Isdelete && hm.HolidayDate.Year == 2015
            orderby hm.HolidayDate ascending
            select new HolidayEntity {
                HolidayDesc = x.HolidayDesc,
                HolidayDate = x.HolidayDate,
                Isactive = x.Isactive,
                Isdelete = x.Isdelete,
                HolidayId = x.HolidayId,
                Zones = GetZonesWithSelectedForHolidays(x.HolidayId)
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```